# What kind of USB-based attacks can be prevented by a VM?

Tags: virtualization, usb, sandbox

The answer provided to this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176207/is-all-the-alarmism-around-badusb-really-called-for-with-respect-to-host-devices) by  forest has a good summary explaining the types of attacks that a malicious USB can do.

Does USB redirection in a VM provide any protection against any of these attack vectors (e.g. confining an exploit in USB class drivers or filesystem drivers to the VM)?

I use KVM/QEMU USB redirection and auto-mounting is disabled on the host OS.